# Something went wrong while sending request. Please try again laravel

Tags: laravel, dictionary

I'm having some trouble getting my Laravel projects to work 
unable to get the distance calculation to work also the request button is give error of Something went wrong while sending request. Please try again.
what could be the problem

thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGDgZ.png)

here is my code

public function send_request(Request $request) {

```
        $this->validate($request, [



                's_latitude' => 'required|numeric',



                'd_latitude' => 'required|numeric',



                's_longitude' => 'required|numeric',



                'd_longitude' => 'required|numeric',



                'service_type' => 'required|numeric|exists:service_types,id',



                'promo_code' => 'exists:promocodes,promo_code',



                'distance' => 'required|numeric',



                'use_wallet' => 'numeric',



                'payment_mode' => 'required|in:CASH,CARD,PAYPAL',



                'card_id' => ['required_if:payment_mode,CARD','exists:cards,card_id,user_id,'.Auth::user()->id],



            ]);







        Log::info('New Request from User: '.Auth::user()->id);



        Log::info('Request Details:', $request->all());







        $ActiveRequests = UserRequests::PendingRequest(Auth::user()->id)->count();







        if($ActiveRequests > 0) {



            if($request->ajax()) {



                return response()->json(['error' => trans('api.ride.request_inprogress')], 500);



            } else {



                return redirect('dashboard')->with('flash_error', 'Already request is in progress. Try again later');



            }



        }







        if($request->has('schedule_date') && $request->has('schedule_time')){



            $beforeschedule_time = (new Carbon("$request->schedule_date $request->schedule_time"))->subHour(1);



            $afterschedule_time = (new Carbon("$request->schedule_date $request->schedule_time"))->addHour(1);







            $CheckScheduling = UserRequests::where('status','SCHEDULED')



                            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)



                            ->whereBetween('schedule_at',[$beforeschedule_time,$afterschedule_time])



                            ->count();











            if($CheckScheduling > 0){



                if($request->ajax()) {



                    return response()->json(['error' => trans('api.ride.request_scheduled')], 500);



                }else{



                    return redirect('dashboard')->with('flash_error', 'Already request is Scheduled on this time.');



                }



            }







        }







        $distance = Setting::get('provider_search_radius', '10');



        $latitude = $request->s_latitude;



        $longitude = $request->s_longitude;



        $service_type = $request->service_type;







        $Providers = Provider::with('service')



            ->select(DB::Raw("(6371 * acos( cos( radians('$latitude') ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians('$longitude') ) + sin( radians('$latitude') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) AS distance"),'id')



            ->where('status', 'approved')



            ->whereRaw("(6371 * acos( cos( radians('$latitude') ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians('$longitude') ) + sin( radians('$latitude') ) * sin( radians(latitude) ) ) ) <= $distance")



            ->whereHas('service', function($query) use ($service_type){



                        $query->where('status','active');



                        $query->where('service_type_id',$service_type);



                    })



            ->orderBy('distance')



            ->get();







        // List Providers who are currently busy and add them to the filter list.







        if(count($Providers) == 0) {



            if($request->ajax()) {



                // Push Notification to User



                return response()->json(['message' => trans('api.ride.no_providers_found')]); 



            }else{



                return back()->with('flash_success', 'No Providers Found! Please try again.');



            }



        }







        try{







            $details = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=".$request->s_latitude.",".$request->s_longitude."&destination=".$request->d_latitude.",".$request->d_longitude."&mode=driving&key=".Setting::get('map_key');







            $json = curl($details);







            $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);







            $route_key = $details['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'];







            $UserRequest = new UserRequests;



            $UserRequest->booking_id = Helper::generate_booking_id();



            $UserRequest->user_id = Auth::user()->id;



            $UserRequest->current_provider_id = $Providers[0]->id;



            $UserRequest->service_type_id = $request->service_type;



            $UserRequest->payment_mode = $request->payment_mode;







            $UserRequest->status = 'SEARCHING';







            $UserRequest->s_address = $request->s_address ? : "";



            $UserRequest->d_address = $request->d_address ? : "";







            $UserRequest->s_latitude = $request->s_latitude;



            $UserRequest->s_longitude = $request->s_longitude;







            $UserRequest->d_latitude = $request->d_latitude;



            $UserRequest->d_longitude = $request->d_longitude;



            $UserRequest->distance = $request->distance;







            if(Auth::user()->wallet_balance > 0){



                $UserRequest->use_wallet = $request->use_wallet ? : 0;



            }







            $UserRequest->assigned_at = Carbon::now();



            $UserRequest->route_key = $route_key;







            if($Providers->count() <= Setting::get('surge_trigger') && $Providers->count() > 0){



                $UserRequest->surge = 1;



            }







            if($request->has('schedule_date') && $request->has('schedule_time')){



                $UserRequest->schedule_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$request->schedule_date $request->schedule_time"));



            }







            $UserRequest->save();







            Log::info('New Request id : '. $UserRequest->id .' Assigned to provider : '. $UserRequest->current_provider_id);











            // update payment mode 







            User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->update(['payment_mode' => $request->payment_mode]);







            if($request->has('card_id')){







                Card::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->update(['is_default' => 0]);



                Card::where('card_id',$request->card_id)->update(['is_default' => 1]);



            }







            (new SendPushNotification)->IncomingRequest($Providers[0]->id);







            foreach ($Providers as $key => $Provider) {







                $Filter = new RequestFilter;



                // Send push notifications to the first provider



                // incoming request push to provider



                $Filter->request_id = $UserRequest->id;



                $Filter->provider_id = $Provider->id; 



                $Filter->save();



            }







            if($request->ajax()) {



                return response()->json([



                        'message' => 'New request Created!',



                        'request_id' => $UserRequest->id,



                        'current_provider' => $UserRequest->current_provider_id,



                    ]);



            }else{



                return redirect('dashboard');



            }







        } catch (Exception $e) {



            if($request->ajax()) {



                return response()->json(['error' => trans('api.something_went_wrong')], 500);



            }else{



                return back()->with('flash_error', 'Something went wrong while sending request. Please try again.');



            }



        }



    }
```

Comment: You should install Xdebug to debug application line by line. It is just known that error has happened somewhere in try {} block. Also would help if you set response message in catch () {} block to be $e->getMessage() for error and flash_error. Disclaimer: just for dev purposes. But certainly, you need to check how to install Xdebug and use it for better development and debugging.

Comment: Look at the console for the error

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/projects/book/asset/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: @Adeola try disabling all validations.. then turn validation on one by one.